# Highcharts renderTo container not found (error 13)

Tags: highcharts

I'm getting error 13 (renderTo/container not found) [in this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/L1nW3H1399j1MjelMPUA?p=preview) but the container div exists, any idea why I'm getting this error?

HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
(function ($) {

  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({             
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line'
      }
      ,xAxis: {
          categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
          'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
       },
      series: [{
          name: 'Tokyo',
          data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
          }, {
              name: 'London',
              data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
       }]
  });

 }(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You need to use jquery ready function:
$(document).ready(function() {
  ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use jquery ready function or move your script named app.js at the end of the body tag to that the script is executed after the 'container' has rendered as html and Highchart is able to locate it in the DOM.